# Making a JSON call from PHP

Tags: php, json

Not sure why but I am not getting anything back from the json call. I echo'ed the content out and pasted to my url bar of my browser and it works. Is there some sort of domain problem here that I need to address?

```
$connect = open_db();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT search_id, search_term FROM search WHERE search_poi_id IS NULL");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $call = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$row["search_term"]."&sensor=false";
    $json = file_get_contents($call);
    print_r($json);
}
close_db($connect);
```

Comment: Does *any* website work? Is port 80 blocked on your server, for your webserver?

Comment: My solution to debug AJAX/PHP issues is to comment out all of the PHP code except for a single `echo('Hello World!');` and then just try to get the JavaScript to `alert()` the response out.  If you can get that to work, the issue is in your PHP.  If not, it may be that your JavaScript that has an error

Comment: @watcher: The OP is already debugging using `print_r`.

Comment: What are the contents of `$row["search_term"]`? You should be using `urlencode($row["search_term"])`.

Comment: Lol, it needed to be urlencoded, problem solved. The spaces where causing problems. urlencode($row["search_term"]) done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) may not always work for external URLs. From php.net:

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. See `fopen()` for more details on how to specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.

Comment: Could you link to that documentation?

Comment: how do I get it to work, or if their is a better way how would I manage it?

Comment: I tried...

echo(file_get_contents('...google's address...')); and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

So the echo-ing works? Thus, there is valid JSON? And now what is the problem? If you want JSON to an Array, then `json_decode()` is what you want.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to further process the data, You could do it like this:

```
$data = array();
$connect = open_db();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT search_id, search_term FROM search WHERE search_poi_id IS NULL");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $call = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$row["search_term"]."&sensor=false";
    $data[] = json_decode(file_get_contents($call));
}
close_db($connect);

foreach($data as $d)
    print_r($d);
```

With this data which should be an array of arrays You can then do whatever You want...

EDIT:

If `file_get_contents()` is not working, try this:

```
$data = array();
$connect = open_db();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT search_id, search_term FROM search WHERE search_poi_id IS NULL");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $call = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$row["search_term"]."&sensor=false";
    $handle = fopen($call, "rb");
    $contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
    fclose($handle);
    $data[] = json_decode($contents);
}
close_db($connect);

foreach($data as $d)
    print_r($d);
```

Comment: file_get_contents($call) returns nothing, but if i put the contents of $call into the url bar of my browser it returns json code.

Comment: Ahaa, I thought file_get_contents() is returning sth... Will edit my post to try other method.

Comment: $call = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=&sensor=false"; returns { "results" : [], "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS" } where as $call = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=TS25 4HQ&sensor=false"; returns nothing except when it is placed in the browser I get json code!